# Show that $\lim_{n\to\infty}\int_X u_n \,d\mu=\int_x u\, d\mu$

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

Let $(X,\mathcal{A},\mu)$ be a probability space, let $(u_n)_{n\geq 1}\subseteq \mathcal{M}^+(\mathcal{A})$ and $u\in \mathcal{M}^+(\mathcal{A})$. Suppose that $u_n\to u$ uniformly. The problem is to show that $\lim_{n\to\infty}\int_X u_n \,d\mu=\int_X u\, d\mu$. Since $v_n\leq ||v_n||:=\sup_{x\in A} |v_n(x)|$, we get $|\int_X u_n \,d\mu|\leq \int_X |u_n| \,d\mu\leq ||v_n||$, because $\mu$ is a probability. Should I use Lebesgue Dominated Convergence here?

Consider the measure space $(\mathbb{R},\mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R}),\lambda)$. I need to find a sequence $(v_n)_{n\geq 1}\subseteq \mathcal{M}^+(\mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R}))$ such that $v_n\to 0$ uniformly, but $\lim_{n\to\infty}\int_\mathbb{R} v_n \,d\lambda\neq 0$.

The notations used here are from Schilling's "Measures, Integrals and Martingales".

**Edit**: $\mathcal{M}^+(\mathcal{A})$ stands for the family of the $\mathcal{A}$-measureable positive real functions. $\mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R})$ is the Borel sets in $\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: What is $\mathcal M^+(\mathcal A)$ ?

Comment: you do not need dominated convergence, $u_n \to u$ is uniformly, hence you could exchange limit and integral

Comment: @Surb I have edited the post

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $\varepsilon>0$.

If $u_n\to u$ uniformly, then, there exists an $n_0$, such that
$$
n\ge n_0\qquad\Longrightarrow\qquad \sup_{x\in X}|u_n(x)-u(x)|<\varepsilon.
$$
Hence, if $n\ge n_0$, then
$$
\Big|\int_X u_n\,d\mu-\int_X u\,d\mu\,\Big|\le \int_X \big|u_n-u\big|\,d\mu\le \varepsilon \int_Xd\mu =\varepsilon,
$$
and hence
$$
\lim_{n\to\infty}\int_X u_n\,d\mu=\int_X u\,d\mu.
$$
In case of the Lebesgue measure on $\mathbb R$, consider, 
$$
u_n=\frac{1}{n}\chi_{[0,n]}.
$$
Then $u_n\to 0$,uniformly, but $\int_{\mathbb R}\chi_n\,d\lambda=1$.

Comment: What if we got the case $\int_X u\, d\mu =\infty$?

Comment: In which case? In the case of the probability measure or in $\mathbb R$?